# Get numbers RegExp in big text

Tags: javascript, regex

I try to get some data from such big text file

```
29.10.2015  Финикс - Даллас П 95:111 (22:24, 23:30, 21:34, 29:23)
    1.4     3.1
31.10.2015  Финикс - Портленд   В 110:92 (27:23, 28:26, 28:20, 27:23)       1.54        2.65
01.11.2015  Портленд    - Финикс    В 90:101 (23:27, 25:29, 23:18, 19:27)
    1.8     2.05
03.11.2015  Л.А. Клипперс   - Финикс    П 102:96 (22:23, 26:16, 27:33, 27:24)       1.22        4.5
```

I try to get `Финикс - Даллас` and `95:111`

```
t1: Финикс 
t2: Даллаc
s1: 95
s2: 111
```

I'm new in RegExp so it's hard to me. Here the begining that I try to do https://regex101.com/r/bD0uR5/1. Thanks!

Comment: Your regex link is not the same as your example.

Comment: arrr give me 1 minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it works for you like this, maybe you could provide more sample data to get it right

```
(?:\d+\.?){3}\s+([^\d]+)\s+-\s+([^\d]+)\s+(\d+):(\d+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/fL2qZ4/1